# Laravel 5 image class conflict

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5, laravel-facade

I have a image model, but after I have started using intervention image to resize images, I have a problem with class conflict because they both have the class name Image.

I have tried to change the alias in app.php, so that intervention facade name is imageIntervention instead of image:

```
'ImageIntervention'     => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'
```

But how do I use this facade in my imageController?

Thanks - Andreas

Comment: What do you mean? Just use it like you would use `Image`... e.g. `ImageIntervention::make(...)`

Comment: @lukasgeiter - I tried that, but when I do, I get this error: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\ImageIntervention' not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use it like you would use `Image`... e.g. `ImageIntervention::make(...)`

Don't forget to import the alias:

```
use ImageIntervention;
```

Or prepend each call by a backslash:

```
\ImageIntervention::make(...)
```

Otherwise PHP will try to find an `ImageIntervention` class inside your current namespace.

---

By the way, you probably don't have to rename `Image` to `ImageIntervention` because your model is namespaced (at least per default, `App\Image`). However I would still leave it that way to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `ImageIntervention` in your controller.

Just add:

```
use ImageIntervention;
```

before class definition of your controller.